# Qt GraphicsScene: how to create a new layer?

Tags: qt, graphics

I have a `QGraphicsView`, displaying `QGraphicsScene`. User can zoom and pan the scene with buttons. This operations are realized with `QGraphicsView` functions, such as `scale()`.
Now I want to draw some transparent pixmaps over it, which are not to be transformed  by user actions. How can I place them separate from the `graphicsView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want something to be drawn on the `QGraphicsView` that is *completely* independent of the scene transformations, you can subclass `QGraphicsView` and draw those items as part of the (overridden) `paintEvent` method.

```
void MyView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
  // Call the base paintEvent to do the "normal" stuff.
  QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);

  // Paint your other stuff. Note that you have to create the QPainter on 
  // the viewport.
  QPainter painter(viewport());
  painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
  // ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when the view is scrolled. It is suitable only for transformations which invalidate the whole view.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag to the pixmap items you do not want to get scaled.

> The item ignores inherited transformations (i.e., its position is
>   still anchored to its parent, but the parent or view rotation, zoom or
>   shear transformations are ignored). This flag is useful for keeping
>   text label items horizontal and unscaled, so they will still be
>   readable if the view is transformed. When set, the item's view
>   geometry and scene geometry will be maintained separately. You must
>   call deviceTransform() to map coordinates and detect collisions in the
>   view. By default, this flag is disabled. This flag was introduced in
>   Qt 4.3. Note: With this flag set you can still scale the item itself,
>   and that scale transformation will influence the item's children.

Use the [`setFlag`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag) function for doing it:

```
pixmapItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
```

Comment: This flag does not prevent GraphicsView from looking away from the items with, say, ensureVisible()

Comment: This flag only affects the item if the view gets scaled. There is no flag for handling scene panning. If you want your objects to be always visible at the same position, except this flag you should explicitly call the setPos of those items every time a scene repainting takes place

Answer (score 0):

I like Dave's answer; for a simple HUD that would be a good way. However, you can do something like that without subclassing and manual painting: Just create two scenes and two views and put them on top of each other, for example into the same spot of a QGridLayout. Thus you have two completely independend "layers" just as you wanted.